# SEGV in gcc's std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unordered-map

I have encountered a SEGV in gcc 4.7.2's `unordered_map`

in `find()` it calls `_M_find_node`, which in turn calls `_M_find_before_node`, passing in the **bucket number**, the **key** we're searching for, and the **hash code**.

In `_M_find_before_node`, it looks up the first node in the bucket in question:

```
_BaseNode* __prev_p = _M_buckets[__n];
```

and then gets the node following this:

```
_Node* __p = static_cast<_Node*>(__prev_p->_M_nxt);
```

The problem is that `__prev_p->_M_nxt` is null; and `_M_equals` tries to dereference it and causes the seg fault.

I'm not 100% clued up on the inner workings of `unordered_map` - is it a requirement that the first node in a bucket's `_M_nxt` be non-null, or is this a bug?

The code in question is here:

```
  // Find the node whose key compares equal to k in the bucket n. Return nullptr
  // if no node is found.
  template<typename _Key, typename _Value,
       typename _Allocator, typename _ExtractKey, typename _Equal,
       typename _H1, typename _H2, typename _Hash, typename _RehashPolicy,
       bool __chc, bool __cit, bool __uk>
    typename _Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey,
            _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy,
            __chc, __cit, __uk>::_BaseNode*
    _Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal,
           _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __chc, __cit, __uk>::
    _M_find_before_node(size_type __n, const key_type& __k,
            typename _Hashtable::_Hash_code_type __code) const
    {
      _BaseNode* __prev_p = _M_buckets[__n];
      if (!__prev_p)
    return nullptr;
      _Node* __p = static_cast<_Node*>(__prev_p->_M_nxt); // __p is null here!!
      for (;; __p = __p->_M_next())
    {
      if (this->_M_equals(__k, __code, __p))
        return __prev_p;
      if (!(__p->_M_nxt) || _M_bucket_index(__p->_M_next()) != __n)
        break;
      __prev_p = __p;
    }
      return nullptr;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you show the code that triggered this bug? If the code is correct, you should be filing a bug report. If not, you'll get your problem solved :)

Comment: Personally I would be looking for bugs in my own code first. Do you have a snippet of your own code that reproduces this bug?

Comment: Can't repro in a simple exemplar - am trying to! :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not 100% clued up on the inner workings of `unordered_map` - is it a requirement that the first node in a bucket's `_M_nxt` be non-null, or is this a bug?

The question is obviously specific to GCC's implementation, but I'm pretty sure that if `_M_buckets[__n]` is non-null then `_M_buckets[__n]->_M_nxt` should be non-null too.

i.e. if the bucket is empty then `_M_buckets[__n]==nullptr`, if the bucket is non-empty then `_M_buckets[__n]->_M_nxt` is the first node in the bucket.

Try building with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and see if it identifies a problem with your code, it's possible there's a bug but it's more likely you've corrupted the container somehow or are using it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Question is rather old now, but I step on the same issue lately and here is sample code how to reproduce it.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map< std::string, int > m_Map{};

   m_Map.insert(std::make_pair("a", 0x61));
   auto count{1000u};

   auto t_remove = std::thread([&m_Map, &count]() {

      while (1)
      {
         m_Map.erase("a");
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(count));
         if(count > 10)
         {
            count-=10;
         }
         else
         {
             count = 1000u;
         }
         m_Map.insert(std::make_pair("a", 0x61));
      }
   });

   while (1)
   {
      auto it = m_Map.find("a");

      if (it != m_Map.end())
      {
         std::cerr << "Map has a " << it->first << " = " << it->second << "\n";
      }
      else
      {
         std::cerr << "Map does not have a \"a\"\n";
      }
   }

   t_remove.join();
   return 0;
}
```

Which results after couple iterations in (gdb):

```
    Thread 1 "find_stress_tes" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040505b in std::__detail::_Equal_helper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, unsigned long, true>::_S_equals (__eq=..., __extract=..., __k="a", __c=4993892634952068459, __n=0x0)
    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1322
1322        { return __c == __n->_M_hash_code && __eq(__k, __extract(__n->_M_v())); }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040505b in std::__detail::_Equal_helper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, unsigned long, true>::_S_equals (__eq=..., __extract=..., __k="a", __c=4993892634952068459, __n=0x0)
    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1322
#1  0x0000000000404b2a in std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_equals (this=0x7fffffffdd40, __k="a", 
    __c=4993892634952068459, __n=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1704
#2  0x00000000004044ef in std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_find_before_node (this=0x7fffffffdd40, __n=1, 
    __k="a", __code=4993892634952068459) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:1433
#3  0x0000000000403e50 in std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_find_node (this=0x7fffffffdd40, __bkt=1, __key="a", 
    __c=4993892634952068459) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:632
#4  0x000000000040392b in std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::find (this=0x7fffffffdd40, __k="a")
    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:1307
#5  0x0000000000403675 in std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> > >::find (this=0x7fffffffdd40, 
    __x="a") at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:615
#6  0x000000000040184b in main () at ../find_stress_test/main.cpp:40
```

Reason for that is simple, concurrent access, solution would be synchronization.

I hope that will help someone ;)

Comment: this is very neat, and indeed shall be marked as correct answer.

Comment: @HubertLiberacki How is it neat? It's just [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because two threads are in a data race. There should have been synchronization accessing the shared map. This code is simply a blatant bug and anything could happen.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have detected an error in the gcc `std::unorderd_map` implementation, the most likely cause of your error is that you did something like:

```
std::unorderd_map<MyKey, MyValue> my_map;
auto it = my_map.find(some_key); // if some_key was not found, it == my_map.end()
do something with *it;           // kaboom! derefence of past-the-end iterator
```

If that's the case, replace it with

```
if (it != my_map.end()) {
    do something with *it;
}
```